# Difference between Raytac mdbt40 and vanilla Nordic nRF51822

Tags: bluetooth

Since I can get easily the nRF51822, but not the mdbt40, can someone give me a brief idea of what is the latter doing more than the former?

I want to hook this chip to an arduino, to replace an HC-08 that I am currently using (which is not BLE), but I found that the few add-on for Arduino on sale, are based on mdbt40, which is using nRF51822, and I can't see what is the difference among the 2, even looking at the datasheet.

Comment: Are you speaking on a bare nRF51822 chip around which you will have to implement your own circuit, or of some random board of unknown design?

Comment: Bare chip; planning to connect only the signal for the serial-to-bluetooth pins, I don't need much more than that. I am happy with the hc-08, but I want something low power, which is why I did choose the nRF51822

Comment: Well, realize you are dealing with a QFN IC and a 2.4 GHz RF circuit involving a number of support components you will need to procure and place on a board you will need to design and fabricate.  This can certainly be done - especially if you closely follow Nordic's recommendations -  but is a quite a bit more involved than working with a premade module.  And of course you will need to come up with software to load.  If you are prepared to do all that, it's kind of odd that you would be asking this question instead of already knowing what would be involved.

Comment: Thanks for the details; I was wondering if the extra effort is worth, compared to get a pre-made module; I am a beginner, so from your comment, I assume that the mdbt40 would be a better choice, compared to deal with the bare chip itself. I thought that the vanilla chip would come ready to go, but as you pointed out, I would also need to put on software to make it work, so it is not really in my alley. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [Nordic](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/3rd-Party-Bluetooth-low-energy-Modules), MDBT40 is a 3rd party Bluetooth module. This boards use Nordic's Bluetooth chip (nRF51822) and add the crystals, resistors, capacitors, and the antenna needed to work.

Both Nordic (producer of the nRF51822) and [Raytac](https://raytac.blog/2017/02/13/why-use-raytac-ble-module/) (producer of the MDBT40) say the main advantage of the modules is that they are compliant with regulatory institutions (FCC in the USA, Telec in Japan, CE in EU, IC in Canada, KC in Korea, SRRC in China, NCC in Taiwan). This alone could save you up to $60,000 US dollars of certifications and product inspections in the case you would want to place your product in the market.

The second biggest advantage the module could give you is in costs of production. Buying a single MDBT40 may be cheaper than buying an nRF51822 and all the components needed for it to work. With the nRF51822 you will need to look at Nordic's documentation and find the requirements or recommendations for the PCB.

If you are a beginner or want to bootstrap a product the MDBT40 is simpler and less expensive.